# how can I transfering many files insted of 1 file over a socket

Tags: java

This codes sending one specific file, how can I send a list of files from one directory  (Server) to another directory (Client) using socket? Help please.

Server Class

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(123456);
    File myFile = new File("s.pdf");
    while (true) {
      Socket sock = servsock.accept();
      byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
      bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
      OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
      os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
      os.flush();
      sock.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Client Class

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 123456);
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("s.pdf");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Tar/compress on the client, send over a single file, and then untar/uncompress on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sender could prefix each file's data with the length of the file. This will enable the receiver to work out when one file ends and the next one begins.